# Firefox scrollbar unresponsive to click using overflow auto and pointer-events none

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, overflow

Scrollbar in boxes with both overflow auto and pointer-events none are not responsive to clicks in firefox.

I have created a very basic jsfiddle reproducing the bug:

http://jsfiddle.net/PgaeC/2/

```
.out {
    overflow: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 100px;
}

.in {
    height: 200px;
}
```

this works in chrome and internet explorer (tested with ie9 and ie10)
in firefox the scrollbar is unresponsive and cannot be clicked at all.

any idea how to give clicks back to the scrollbar in firefox ?

What i want is a box handling click, and another box sometimes going over it, grabbing clicks on its own, with a space on top where you can still interact with the bottom box, and the scrollbar spanning on the whole page
like this : http://jsfiddle.net/NczQG/2/

EDIT: created bug in mozilla bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=880671

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what 'grabbing clicks' is, but you say the way these two fiddles act in Chrome or IE represent how you want it to work overall?

Comment: yeah. you cannot interact with the scrollbar using the mouse left button (clickin the arrows, or grabbing the handle) in firefox. by grabbing clicks i mean i can handle click events & the like, meaning i can't have a plain div over it stopping the clicks from propagating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as seen in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=880671)

the mozilla team fixed it :
http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/f8bf18dceb1c

so it's fixed on the nightly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working anymore...