# Scrollbar is not clickable in Firefox when using pointer-events: none

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm trying to create a scrollable sidebar where each element would have a tooltip. This became way harder than what I expected:

Here is a first attempt, using a naive approach:

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Box = ({ index }) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
      style={{
        border: "1px solid grey",
        width: "2em",
        height: "2em",
        display: "flex",
        flex: "0 0 auto",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
      <span>{index}</span>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          bottom: "100%",
          background: "black",
          color: "white",
          display: hover ? "block" : "none"
        }}
      >
        tooltip
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const items = useMemo(() => {
    return Array(30)
      .fill(0)
      .map((_, i) => <Box index={i} />);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", maxHeight: "100vh" }}
      className="App"
    >
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 auto",
          maxHeight: "100vh",
          overflowY: "auto",
          marginTop: "2em",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      >
        {items}
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 1em",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          cursor: "pointer"
        }}
        onCLick={console.log}
      >
        click
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "1 1 auto",
          backgroundColor: "grey",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        The "click" area is accessible,
        <br />
        but the tooltip is clipped
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo accessible [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-clipped-dtpckv?file=/src/App.js:0-1870)

As mentioned there, the "click" area is accessible, but the tooltips will be clipped:

[image: tooltip is clipped]

As a workaround, I extended the scrollable area, so that the part containing the items goes beyond the lateral toolbar.

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Box = ({ index }) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
      style={{
        border: "1px solid grey",
        width: "2em",
        height: "2em",
        display: "flex",
        flex: "0 0 auto",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
      <span>{index}</span>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 0,
          bottom: "100%",
          background: "black",
          color: "white",
          display: hover ? "block" : "none"
        }}
      >
        tooltip
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const items = useMemo(() => {
    return Array(30)
      .fill(0)
      .map((_, i) => <Box index={i} />);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: "100vh"
      }}
      className="App"
    >
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "1 1 auto",
          backgroundColor: "grey",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        The "click" area is accessible,
        <br />
        but the tooltip is clipped
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 1em",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          cursor: "pointer"
        }}
        onClick={console.log}
      >
        click
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 2.1em",
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            alignItems: "flex-end",
            width: "10em",
            maxHeight: "100%",
            overflowY: "auto",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            position: "absolute",
            right: 0,
            top: 0
          }}
        >
          {items}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollarea-wider-f2nm43) is the demo

But now, the "click" area cannot be clicked anymore. To solve this, I added a pointer-events: none on the extended scrollable area:

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Box = ({ index }) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
      style={{
        pointerEvents: "all",
        border: "1px solid grey",
        width: "2em",
        height: "2em",
        display: "flex",
        flex: "0 0 auto",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
      <span>{index}</span>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 0,
          bottom: "100%",
          background: "black",
          color: "white",
          display: hover ? "block" : "none"
        }}
      >
        tooltip
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const items = useMemo(() => {
    return Array(30)
      .fill(0)
      .map((_, i) => <Box index={i} />);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "90vw",
        overflow: "hidden"
      }}
      className="App"
    >
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "1 1 auto",
          backgroundColor: "grey",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        The "click" area is accessible,
        <br />
        but the tooltip is clipped
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 1em",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          cursor: "pointer"
        }}
        onClick={console.log}
      >
        click
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 2.1em",
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            pointerEvents: "none",
            alignItems: "flex-end",
            width: "10em",
            maxHeight: "100%",
            overflowY: "auto",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            position: "absolute",
            right: 0,
            top: 0
          }}
        >
          {items}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollarea-wider-with-pointer-event-clthvw) is the demo

Now, the "click" area is clickable, the tooltips are showing up, **but**, the scrollbar doesn't respond to clicks on Firefox. A [10 years answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900365/firefox-scrollbar-unresponsive-to-click-using-overflow-auto-and-pointer-events-n) is saying that this has been fixed, but this is not what I experiment on my end. A [comment from 1 year ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=880671) seems to notice the same issue.

Do you know any workaround for my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this? Changes are marked with a  red square

https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollarea-wider-forked-sz9qnf?file=/src/App.js:0-2203

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Box = ({ index }) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
      style={{
        border: "1px solid grey",
        width: "2em",
        height: "2em",
        display: "flex",
        flex: "0 0 auto",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
      <span>{index}</span>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 0,
          bottom: "100%",
          background: "black",
          color: "white",
          display: hover ? "block" : "none"
        }}
      >
        tooltip
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const items = useMemo(() => {
    return Array(30)
      .fill(0)
      .map((_, i) => <Box index={i} />);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: "100vh"
      }}
      className="App"
    >
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "1 1 auto",
          backgroundColor: "grey",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        The tooltip is ok
        <br />
        But the "click" area is unaccessible
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 1em",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          cursor: "pointer",
          zIndex: 10 // z index to be in front and be clickable
        }}
        onClick={console.log}
      >
        click
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 3.1em", // increase width
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            alignItems: "flex-end",
            width: "10em",
            maxHeight: "100%",
            overflowY: "auto",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            position: "absolute",
            right: 0,
            top: 0
          }}
        >
          {items}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That looks promising! Thanks a lot. Can you confirm why you increased the width of the side bar?

Comment: Your welcome! It was a bit of try and error, i increased the width to push the click div to the left.

Comment: Because you were trying to move the click away from the area needed for the tooltips, right? Actually, if you pay attention, I believe that your z-index solved the issue on its own. I believe that there is no need to increase the width. Can you confirm that I'm not missing something?

Comment: Only the z index is enough to make It work. But without the width increase It doesnt look Very good to me, the click text overlaps with the numbers

Comment: Yeah. Don't worry, my real app doesn't look like that xD